If method whereDate good when making fileter by datetime field?
In laravel 10/mysql 8 app I have a table with datetime field:
public function up(): void
{
        Schema::create('reactions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('user_id')->nullable()->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('CASCADE');

        $table->morphs('model');
        $table->unsignedTinyInteger('action');

        $table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();

        $table->unique(['model_type', 'model_id', 'user_id', 'action'], 'reactions_4fields_unique');
        $table->index(['model_type', 'model_id', 'action', 'created_at'], 'reactions_4fields_index');
        $table->index(['created_at', 'model_type', 'model_id'], 'reactions_3fields_index');
    });
}

and running request by date :
$this->reactions = Reaction
    ::query()->whereDate('created_at', $this->filterAtDate)
    ->groupBy('action')
    ->orderBy('reaction_count', 'desc')
    ->select(
        $reactionTb . '.action',
        DB::raw('count(' . $reactionTb . '.id) as reaction_count'))
    ->get()->toArray();

I check explain of the request :
explain   SELECT `reactions`.`action`, count(reactions.id)     AS reaction_count
    FROM `reactions`
    WHERE date(`created_at`) = '2024-05-14 00:00:00'
    GROUP BY `action`
    ORDER BY `reaction_count` desc

and see as created_at is time too "date" method is used and in explain output with
Possible keys:
reactions_4fields_unique,reactions_4fields_index

Key :
reactions_4fields_index

Not sure if indexing of created_at field would work here ?  Is whereDate method good here ?
I see decision for latest version for mysql and postgresql...

The created_at index would not work because you are using DATE(created_at) which is not the same as created_at

I found this related my issue
https://dev.to/timoye/stop-using-wheredate-laravel-5h42
article and not sure if matter actually in whereDate method ?
Looks like I try to compare datetime and date - that can not be done without type casting into date type
with method
`DATE(created_at)`

on server side. Are some other methods to make indexing to work with ir?

If you do whereRaw('created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?', [ $this->filterAtDate, $this->filterAtDate->addDay() ]) (assuming filterAtDate is today's date and a carbon instance) it might work because it directly uses the created_at column with given values.

Thank you! But passing 2 parameters :
::query()->whereRaw('created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?', [ $filterAtDate, $filterAtDate->addDay() ]) 
Where
$filterAtDate = ‘'2024-05-17’  
I check invalid sql-statements :
  SELECTreactions.action, count(reactions.id)     AS reaction_count      FROM reactions     WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2024-05-18 00:00:00'     AND '2024-05-18 00:00:00'      GROUP BYaction     ORDER BYreaction_countdesc 
Parameters invalidly passed ?

I mean in tracement in both case '2024-05-18 00:00:00'

if your carbon instance is not immutable use (clone $filterAtDate)->addDay()

I cloned 1 more var but passing 2 vars in ::query()->whereRaw('created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?', [ $filterAtDate, $filterAtDateTill ])  looks like only 2nd var is used for both vars. Is my syntax invalid ?

I found a decision with method :
::query()->whereBetween('created_at', [$filterAtDate, $filterAtDate->clone()->addDays(1)])

Making clone in this way I have 2 different dates in sql tracement
